# windows phone 8.1 textbox remove dash and select option

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, windows-phone

I want to remove the flashing dash from a TextBox when the user presses it and to stop the user from being give the option to select and copy text.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you need exactly, there are many ways you can achieve this.

1. Call `Clipboard.SetText("")` whenever `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events are triggered.
2. Override `SelectionChanged` and do `e.Handled = true`.
3. Create your own custom control by inheriting `TextBox`, set a custom Template, and manually add/remove characters for every `KeyDown` event.

There doesn't seem to be a way to change the flashing caret/cursor on Windows Universal apps, and there is no way to disable the clipboard either.